# How to create a table for a table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am having a hard time thinking how to create or to have the table/s for the members who are going to join the table room. I have two kind of members

- `holder` - one who creates a room
- `member` - one who will join the room with a `room_code`.

How can I create the table for the members in that room?

Table `members`:

- `member_id`
- `member_type`
- `member_name`
- `member_username`
- `member_password`

Table `room`:

- `room_id`
- `room_name`
- `room_code`
- `room_section`
- `room_desc`
- `room_holder_id`
- `room_limit`
- `date_created`

Comment: I improved the formatting and fixed the title. You need to show what you have tried so far and make the title and question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of your table is going to depend a lot on the requirements you need fulfilled.

In the situation where a `member` can only ever be assigned to a single `room`, but `room`s can have many `member`s, then the answer that Double H gave is exactly what you're looking for:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
 member_id INT,
 member_type VARCHAR,
 member_name VARCHAR,
 member_username VARCHAR,
 member_password VARCHAR,
 room_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES room(room_id)
)
```

Now, if a `member` could participate in more than a single room, and rooms can have more than a single `member`, you start getting off into other types of relationships (e.g. many-to-many).

The MySQL documentation as well as textbooks (e.g. from the library) can all do really good jobs of explaining the different types of relationships inside a RDBMS (relational database management system). Understanding the logical way tables are joined is a key step before understanding how to physically join them in the database (like, for example, through phpmyadmin).

For implementation details of a many-to-many relationship, there are many resources online including this one by Pinal Dave: [Many-to-many Relationships](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/08/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-many-to-many-relationships-day-8-of-35/). It basically explains that a third table is necessary to successfully make the relation.

Comment: how can i constuct the many to many relationship in my database, cause 1 member can also have more than 1 room

Comment: I put in a link to a good online resource. To be honest, however, Stack Overflow isn't the place to learn about database table relationships. Books have been written, classes have been made, even specialized degrees and certificates have been created to teach those concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Tables as `room` and `members` provide a `foriegn key` index to `room_id` to `members` column which is `primary key` of `room` table